# Negative Variance LS Estimator

Tags: regression, variance, modeling

I am estimating moisture utilizing measurements from a thermal imaging camera. For context, my implementation becomes a FIR filter, and is very similar to the Weiner Filter.

I am using several pixels and frames, but my problems also occur if only one pixel (with several frames) are taken into account. Essentially, I am trying to estimate moisture of an object by measuring the temperature, taking several measurements into account.

**Notation**

All values are zero mean after variable shift.

m: moisture, scalar

y: measurements (temperature), nx1 vector. Contains measurements from 1 pixel and n frames.

$R_{my}$: cross-correlation, $E[my^T]$

$R_{yy}$: auto-correlation, $E[yy^T]$

The LS estimator is attained by any solution $K$ to $KR_{yy}=R_{my}$. I have a dataset from which I can derive $R_{my}$ and $R_{yy}$, and by inverting $R_{yy}$/solving a systems of equations, I can determine $K$. The quality of the dataset is pretty good.

Estimator: $\hat{m}=Ky$

**The problem**

When I determine the estimator error (MSE), I find negative variance.

$E[\tilde{m}^2]=E[m^2]-R_{my}R_{yy}^{-1}R_{ym}$

If I evaluate this, then I find that it is negative, which is erroneous. Can anyone provide any feedback or guess on why it could be like this? Is this common when utilizing data? I would be more comfortable with supplied values, eg an exercise.

**Comment on variance expression**

I have proved the above relation before, but I know that it involves some matrix inversion I don't feel like doing. Here is a much simpler derivation;

$E[\tilde{m}\tilde{m}^T]=E[(m-\hat{m})(m-\hat{m})^T]=E[(m-Ky)(m-Ky)^T]=E[m^2] - E[my^T]K^T-KE[ym^T] +KE[yy^T]K^T$

Which, if I evaluate, is identical to the result I showed previously.

Comment: Why not just sum up the squared errors $(m - \hat{m})^2$?  That's guaranteed to be both correct and non-negative.